# How can I create utf-8 Text on a GUI Canvas using Tkinter for a Python Program?

Tags: python, utf-8, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I am attempting to create text on a Canvas using Tkinter for Python. However when I execute the following code it prints properly to the console, but does not display correctly to the Tkinter Canvas. Displaying the following for the print command: "Heres a dope lil recap of our European adventures ..."

```
from Tkinter import *    
for tweet in alltweets:
    print tweet.text.encode("utf-8")
    t = tweet.text.encode("utf-8")
    u = unicode(t, "utf-8")
    w.create_text(220, 480, fill="white", text = api.get_user(tweet.user.id).screen_name + " " + u)
```

It does correctly display any tweets not including emojis on the Canvas. I am beginning to think that Tkinter is not capable of doing this work, but I don't want to redo all the other work that is associated. However if I have to and it would be a better/easier solution I'm willing to do whatever.

Comment: Tkinter's should be able to print some unicode (see [UnicodeSupport](http://tkinter.unpythonic.net/wiki/UnicodeSupport)). Maybe your font doesn't have the required glyphs?

Comment: @solarc Well this is a good question. I'm using Veranda for the regular text in the application. I see in googling that Symbola font is popular. However how to add Symbola to my project or Python in general is a little harder to find information on... Much less how to deal with multiple fonts in a variable. I'll keep looking assuming this is the issue.